# Comparing form input values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I know there are a few threads on this topic, and in fact I got my code from one such thread, but I just can't seem to get it to run. I'm trying to compare two input boxes in an HTML form using javascript.

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
function checkform(form1)
{
    if(form1.password.value != form1.passwordConfirm.value)
    {
        alert("Passwords must be the same");
        form1.password.focus();
        return true;
    } else {return false;}
}
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!Doctype html>
<script type="C:/wamp/www/Table/" src="javascript.js"></script>
<form name="form1" action="demo_form.asp">
    Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Username cannot be empty.')">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password cannot be empty')">
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password        cannot be empty')"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return checkform(form1);">
</form>
</html>
```

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Shouldn't you have the return true/false reversed

Comment: Just as a tip: instead of passing `form1` to the function use `this.form` do directly hand over the correct dom-element. No need to use a getElementById anymore (for the form itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to assign an `id` to your form, and get that.

Replace:

```
<form name="form1" action="demo_form.asp">
```

With:

```
<form name="form1" action="demo_form.asp" id="myForm">
```

And and this:

```
function checkform(form1){
```

With this:

```
function checkform(){
    var form1 = document.getElementById('myForm')
```

You also need to switch your return statements, to return `false` when the PW's don't match.

The resulting JS / HTML:

```js
function checkform(){
    var form1 = document.getElementById('myForm');
    if(form1.password.value != form1.passwordConfirm.value)
    {
        alert("Passwords must be the same");
        form1.password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="demo_form.asp" id="myForm">
    Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Username cannot be empty.')">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password cannot be empty')">
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password        cannot be empty')"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return checkform();">
</form>
```

Notice how I removed the `else` around the second return statement. It's not needed.

Comment: and reverse the return true and false

Comment: Not necessary, by giving the form a name it is attached to the `document`

Comment: @elzi: A variable that's easily overwritten. It's always a good idea to explicitly get your form.

Comment: How would it be overwritten besides if he gave another element the same name attribute value?

Comment: You've never seen programmers (accidentally) re-use names? Did that _really_ warrant a downvote, just because of a difference in opinion?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the responses! I made all the changes you indicated and it works, thanks! Two quick questions: first, could you help me understand why I needed to switch the true and false? Second, if I only include the call code (i.e.<script type="C:/wamp/www/Table/" src="javascript.js"></script>) it doesn't work. It only works when I paste the actual code into the HTML document. Would you have any idea why that is? Thanks again, appreciate it!

Comment: @Cerbrus Not any more often than I see people re-use IDs. Especially not on a form. Seems like a six of one, half dozen of the other situation. Anyway, your answer is how I'd likely do it too :P

Comment: @Mike: If the passwords don't match, you want to return `false`, to prevent the submit from continuing. (It stops when it gets a `false` returned). A return value of `true` means _"It's okay, go ahead and submit!"_ Second question: That means the `javascript.js` isn't getting included properly. You'll need to use a relative path, as the browser has no clue where `c:/` is, when you're loading the page.

Comment: Ok great, thanks so much for all the info! I still can't get the relative referencing to work, but I'll fiddle around and hopefully come right eventually! Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Take out `return` from the onclick.

`onClick="checkform(form1);"`